# Given an overdetermined system of linear equation, find a subset that can be solved with exact solution

Tags: systems-of-equations, linear-programming

Given a set **A** such that **A** consists of an overdetermined system of linear equation.

Find 
$$
B \subset A
$$
such that B has x equations and x unknowns and has an exact solution.

For example:

In a system where you have 4 unknowns and 7 equations, you can solve this by trying all 4 distinct equations you can create from the 7 equations, and then see if it's solvable.

But the permutations become really big as your overdetermined system grows.

Is there a correct way to do this? Is Linear Programming an option? & if so, how to change this into a linear programming problem?

Comment: By RREF we can select the independent equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the system has an unique solution the standard way is by [RREF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) otherwise we can find an [approximate solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system#Approximate_solutions) by least squares.